# Meaning of Div/Yield in Google Stocks

Tags: stocks

Google stocks lists this thing called "Div/Yield" as two numbers. For example, today, for MMM (3M company), it's "0.59/2.71".

What exactly do these numbers mean? Are they the dividend yield, or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first part "Div" stands for the quarterly dividend in dollars i.e $0.59, whilst the second part "Yield" stands for the dividend yield as a percentage = the annual dividend in dollars divided by the current share price i.e 2.71%.

So in this case the share price would have been $87.08, as ($0.59 * 4 )/$87.08 = 2.71% Dividend Yield.

Comment: If that's true, how can the second price be $21.77 when the current price for the last two months has been over $80?

Comment: @ashes999, I have just looked up the info. for 3M, it is because you wrote down the wrong amount for the dividend, it is actually $2.36 with a yield of 2.71%, so then the share price is $87.14.

Comment: fixed the answer to address the fact that 0.59 is the quarterly div and the the yield is based on the annual div.

Comment: Note that some companies pay dividends monthly or annually. The Div number will then be that monthly or annual amount. Google no longer supports Dividend flags on their charts, so you'll have to do a little math with the Div, Yield and current price to determine the number of payouts/year.